# Threads are not terminating in console application in delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, console-application, delphi-7

Hello friends i have doubt writing multithreaded console application. When i write code for gui application it works perfectly. But same code does not work for console application.Why is it so?

```
program Project1;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,syncobjs,forms;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TFileSearcher = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FPath, FMask: string;
    FIncludeSubDir: boolean;
    Fcriticalsection: TCriticalSection;
    I : Int64;
    Size : int64;
    cnt : Longint;
    Procedure Add;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string; IncludeSubDir: boolean);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
 ScannerThread = class(TThread)   //main ScannerThread Declaration
Private
 ScannerChCount : Integer;                                               //Private variable to keep track of currently running threads
Protected
  Procedure ScanchildTerminated(Sender : TObject);                            //TNotifyEvent Procedure That Increment count on sub thread termination
  Procedure Execute(); Override;                                  //Excecute Procedure declaration
Public
End;

var
  Count,Tsize,FCount : Int64;

Procedure ListFolders(const DirName: string; FolderList : Tstringlist);
var
  Path: string;
  F: TSearchRec;
  SubDirName: string;

begin
  Path:= DirName + '\*.*';
  if FindFirst(Path, faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            SubDirName:= IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DirName) + F.Name;
            FolderList.Add(SubdirName);
             ListFolders(SubDirName,FolderList);
          end;
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetDirSize(dir: string; subdir: Boolean): int64;
var
  rec: TSearchRec;
  found: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if dir[Length(dir)] <> '\' then dir := dir + '\';
  found := FindFirst(dir + '*.*', faAnyFile, rec);
  while found = 0 do
  begin
    Inc(Result, rec.Size);
    if (rec.Attr and faDirectory > 0) and (rec.Name[1] <> '.') and (subdir = True) then
      Inc(Result, GetDirSize(dir + rec.Name, True));
    found := FindNext(rec);
  end;
  FindClose(rec);
end;


procedure FindFiles(FilesList: TStringList;Subdir : Boolean; StartDir, FileMask: string);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  DirList,DirlistOnly: TStringList;
  IsFound: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  If StartDir[length(StartDir)] <> '\' then
    StartDir := StartDir + '\';
  IsFound :=
    FindFirst(StartDir+FileMask, faAnyFile-faDirectory, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do begin
   Begin
    FilesList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    Count:= Count + Sr.Size;
   end;
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  // Build a list of subdirectories
  DirList := TStringList.Create;
  IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir+'*.*',
                        faAnyFile
                        , SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do begin
    if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory)<> 0) and
         (SR.Name <> '.') and   (subdir = true) and (sr.name <> '..') then
    Begin
      DirList.Add(StartDir + SR.Name);
    end;
    IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
  end;
  FindClose(SR);

  // Scan the list of subdirectories
  for I := 0 to DirList.Count - 1 do
  Begin
    FindFiles(FilesList, SubDir,DirList[i], FileMask);
  end;
  DirList.Free;
end;

constructor TFileSearcher.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string;
  IncludeSubDir: boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FPath := Path;
  FMask := Mask;
  FIncludeSubDir := IncludeSubDir;
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  //FcriticalSection:= Tcriticalsection.create;
end;

procedure TFileSearcher.Execute;
Var
 FilesList : TStringList;
begin
 Count:=0;
 FilesList:= TStringList.create;
 FindFiles(FilesList,false,fpath,fmask);
 cnt:= FilesList.count;
  I:= GetDirSize(fpath,false);
  Synchronize(Add);
end;

Procedure TFileSearcher.Add;
Begin
 size:=size + I ;
 Tsize:= Tsize + size;
 Fcount:= Fcount + cnt;
 //Form1.Memo2.Lines.add(inttostr(TSize));
 //Form1.Memo1.Lines.add(inttostr(Fcount));
End;

Procedure ScannerThread.Execute; // main ScannerCh Execute Procedure
Var
 Folderlist: Tstringlist;
 I: Integer;
 ScannerCh : array of TFileSearcher;
  Filelist : Tstringlist;
Begin
  ScannerChCount:=0;
  Tsize:=0;
  Fcount:=0;
  Folderlist:= TStringList.create;

  ListFolders('d:\tejas',Folderlist);
 //Memo2.lines.add(inttostr(Folderlist.count));
  SetLength(ScannerCh,Folderlist.count);
        I:=0;                                                            //initialising I
        Repeat
            ScannerCh[i]:=TFileSearcher.Create(true,Folderlist[i],'*.*',true);    //Creating New ScannerCh and assigning Ip to scan
            ScannerCh[I].FreeOnTerminate:=True;
            ScannerCh[I].OnTerminate:= ScanchildTerminated;     //Terminate ScannerCh after its work will finish
            ScannerCh[I].Resume;                            //ScannerCh Started
            //ScannerChCount:=ScannerChCount+1;
            InterlockedIncrement(ScannerChCount);
            I:=I+1;
            Sleep(5);                  //incrementing counter For next ScannerCh
        until I = Folderlist.Count;
        ScannerCh:=nil;

  Repeat                         //Main ScannerCh Waiting For Ip scan ScannerChs to finish
   Sleep(100);
  until ScannerChCount = 0;

  Count:=0;
  FileList:= TStringList.create;
  FindFiles(Filelist,false,'D:\tejas','*.*');
  Writeln(inttostr(fcount + Filelist.Count));
  Writeln(inttostr(GetDirSize('d:\tejas',False) + Tsize ));
  freeandnil(Filelist);
End;

Procedure ScannerThread.ScanchildTerminated(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  //ScannerChCount:=ScannerChCount-1;
  InterlockedDecrement(ScannerChCount); //Increment Count
End;

var
 Scanner : ScannerThread;
 Filelist : Tstringlist;
begin
  Scanner:=Scannerthread.Create(True);     //Creating thread
  Scanner.FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  Scanner.Resume;
  While GetTThreadsCount(GetCurrentProcessId) > 1 do
 begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  CheckSynchronize;
 end;

  Writeln;
  Readln;
end.
```

when i debugged my code I found threads which are getting created are not terminating.Why is it so?.. I kept freeonterminate as true.Can anyone tell me?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? I seem to recall that the use of `Synchronize` requires a message loop at least on some versions of Delphi.

Comment: You are still doing it the wrong way. Even with a new user name. Use a pool of threads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-  when i checked task manager for threads running only 3 threads run at a time.Main thread,Scannerthread and Tfilesearcher thread.i tried debugging so i got to know when a new thread is getting created previous thread is getting destroyed.Still i am getting right output. I kept breakpoint between repeat to until statement.whats going wrong?Why not all threads running concurrently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code specific to console application:

1) direct call of `Synchronize` method; you should not call `Synchronize` in a console application (use other sync methods instead);

2) hidden call of `Synchronize` method in `OnTerminate` event; you should not use `OnTerminate` event in a console application (override `DoTerminate` method instead).

Comment: can you please explain by writing small example?

Comment: You know how to override methods.

Comment: yeah i know how to override method. What to put inside doterminate method?

Comment: @james `InterlockedDecrement(ScannerChCount);` I guess. You should care about synchronization in the overridden `DoTerminate`.

Answer (score 4):

Always with free on terminate threads you need to ask yourself if the process ends before the threads do. Which would explain why they do not terminate.

However, in this case I think there is another explanation. Your use of `Synchronize` won't work in a console app unless you call `CheckSynchronize`.  If you don't call `CheckSynchronize` from the main thread, and you don't, then your threads will block indefinitely when they call `Synchronize`. That call is needed to process the `Synchronize` queue. In a GUI app, the VCL framework takes are of calling `CheckSynchronize` for you. You are left to your own devices in a console app.

In any case the call to `Synchronize` is not needed. You can use `InterlockedIncrement` or `AtomicIncrement` which is faster than locking or invoking on a different thread. It will make your code much simpler too.

And even if you do need serialization, `Synchronize` is the wrong tool for the job. You use `Synchronize` primarily when you need code to execute on the main thread. Typically that's because it is GUI code. You have no GUI. If you need any serialization in your console app, use a lock. For instance a critical section. But don't call `Synchronize`.

---

To modify your code, remove the `Add` method and replace

```
Synchronize(Add);
```

with

```
inc(size, I);
InterlockedIncrement(Fcount, cnt);
InterlockedIncrement(Tsize, size);
```

Or if you want `FCount` and `Tsize` to be incremented atomically then you need a lock. Declare a global critical section and initialize it. Then wrap the increments of `FCount` and `Tsize` in that lock.

```
inc(size, I);
Lock.Acqure;
try
  inc(Fcount, cnt);
  inc(Tsize, size);
finally
  Lock.Release;
end;
```

Comment: He has a `Readln` statement last.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError He might be pressing enter. You are spot on about Synchronize though. The threads will block there.

Comment: how to use checksynchronise?..i have not used it before. It is something new for me.

Comment: You need to call it from the main thread at regular intervals. You can subscribe to an event to wake the main thread up to process the synchronize queue. However, you should simply stop calling `Synchronize`. Calling `Synchronize` will hurt performance. It's not needed. Stop calling it.

Comment: can u write short code for me? so that i will get an idea exactly what to do?

Comment: i tried both but still threads are not terminating.What else is going wrong?

Comment: Don't know. Code is complex. And very messy. Have you attempted to perform some debugging. If the threads are not terminating, what are they doing.

Comment: yes sir i did debugging.Debugger is creating but onterminate event is not happening because of that debugger is not coming out of repeat code until scannerchcount:= 0.

Comment: I think serg's answer explains that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sir if i remove that repeat part and put yours then it is working. Thank you. But threads are terminating when application is terminated

Comment: I just wish you'd ask the question that I've requested you ask. How can this be done with a thread pool?

Comment: You aren't using a thread pool now. You are using a diabolical threading approach. Why don't you ask the question that I've requested you to ask before? Read the comments I've left at your other questions. You know, the ones you asked with one of your other accounts. Having multiple accounts is really annoying btw.